# Issue regarding questions related on anagram in C++

Tags: c++

SO I was asked to solve this question--

"Given two strings, a and b, that may or may not be of the same length, determine the minimum number of character deletions required to make a and b anagrams. Any characters can be deleted from either of the strings."

eg--if strings are abc & cde , the answer is 4.

I wrote the code but it does not seem to work for all test cases. Can anyone guide me?

> ```
> #include<iostream>
> #include<string>
> using namespace std;
> int main(){
>
>   string s1;
>   string s2;
>
>   cin>>s1;
>   cin>>s2;
>   int count=0;
>
>   int arr[26]{0};
>   for(int i{0};i<s1.length();i++){
>     arr[static_cast<int>(s1.at(i))-97]+=1;
>   }
>   for(int i{0};i<s2.length();i++){
>     arr[static_cast<int>(s2.at(i))-97]-=1;
>   }
>
>   for(auto range : arr){
>     if(range!=0){
>         count++;
>     }
>   }
>
>   cout<<count;
>
>   return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: it should be `if(range!=0)count+=abs(range);` assume `'a'==97` and input string are in `['a','z']`

Comment: Someone already ask that, you can check out here:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144320/given-two-strings-a-and-b-determine-the-minimum-number-of-character-deletions